# Error in powershell script

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I am getting the following errors with a script that auto installs all updates in the current directory:

```
At K:\Operating System\ConfigureWindows10\Updates\Install-Updates.ps1:15 char:25
+         $command = "Expand â€“F:* '" + $msu.fullname + "' '" + $PSScr ...
+                               ~~~
Unexpected token 'F:*' in expression or statement.
At K:\Operating System\ConfigureWindows10\Updates\Install-Updates.ps1:29 char:82
+ ... = "Dism.exe /online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup /ResetBase"
+                                                                         ~
The string is missing the terminator: ".
At K:\Operating System\ConfigureWindows10\Updates\Install-Updates.ps1:13 char:5
+     {
+     ~
Missing closing '}' in statement block or type definition.
At K:\Operating System\ConfigureWindows10\Updates\Install-Updates.ps1:10 char:1
+ {
+ ~
Missing closing '}' in statement block or type definition.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

Here is the code body:

```
{
$msu = get-childitem -path $PSScriptRoot -Recurse | where ($_.extension -eq ".msu") | select fullname
foreach($package in $msu)
{
    write-debug $msu.fullname
    $command = "Expand –F:* '" + $msu.fullname + "' '" + $PSScriptRoot + "'"
    write-debug $command
    Invoke-Expression $command
}

$updates = get-childitem -path $PSScriptRoot -Recurse | where ($_.extension -eq ".cab") | select fullname
foreach($update in $updates)
{
    write-debug $update.fullname
    $command = "dism /online /add-package /packagepath:'" + $update.fullname + "'"
    write-debug $command
    Invoke-Expression $command
}

$command = "Dism.exe /online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup /ResetBase"
Invoke-Expression $command
}
```

Comment: When saving script file as UTF-8 use UTF-8 with **BOM**.

Comment: Thanks. The script works however I am getting another error. The script doesn't expand any msu file in directory.

Comment: Update in code :

Comment: $msu = get-childitem -path $PSScriptRoot -Recurse | where ($_.extension -eq ".msu") | select fullname
    foreach($package in $msu)
    {
        write-debug $package.fullname
  $command = "Expand –F:* '" + $package.fullname + "' '" + $PSScriptRoot + "'"
        write-debug $command
        Invoke-Expression $command
    }

Comment: Is this a `-` (minus) or a dash before the F?

Answer (score 1):

After "where" you need a script block which usually is in curly brackets, not in simple ones.

```
 ...| where {$_.extension -eq ".msu"} |...
```

Comment: Changing () to {} did work however the script just executes Dism.exe /online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup /ResetBase. Nothing else is executed.

Comment: In the loop: foreach($package in $msu) {...} you use the $msu.fullname which is not good, you should use the $package.fullname instead.

Answer (score 0):

- You use the var $msu instead of $package in the first foreach.
- Aside from the curly brackets in the where clause, you could omit it
  specifying a `-Filter *.msu` parameter in the Get-ChildItem.
- IMO the select isn't necessary
- the quoting doesn't seem right, use a here string instead

---

Try this (untested)

```
{
    $msu = get-childitem -path $PSScriptRoot -Recurse -Filter *.msu
    foreach($package in $msu){
        write-debug $package.FullName
$command = @'
& Expand.exe –F:* "$package.FullName" "$PSScriptRoot"
'@
        write-debug $command
        Invoke-Expression $command
    }
    $updates = get-childitem -path $PSScriptRoot -Recurse -Filer *.cab
    foreach($update in $updates){
        write-debug $update.fullname
$command = @'
& Dism.exe /online /add-package /packagepath:"$update.FullFame"
'@
        write-debug $command
        Invoke-Expression $command
    }
    $command = "Dism.exe /online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup /ResetBase"
    Invoke-Expression $command
}
```

Comment: At K:\OperatingSystem\ConfigureWindows10\Updates\Extract-Updates.ps1:8 char:5
+     '@
+     ~~
White space is not allowed before the string terminator.
At K:\OperatingSystem\ConfigureWindows10\Updates\Extract-Updates.ps1:4 char:1
+ {
+ ~
Missing closing '}' in statement block or type definition.
At K:\OperatingSystem\ConfigureWindows10\Updates\Extract-Updates.ps1:1 char:1
+ {
+ ~
Missing closing '}' in statement block or type definition.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WhitespaceBeforeHereStringFooter

Comment: Changed the script above removing the indents with the here strings.

Comment: The 2nd and 3rd error refer to a mismatch in closing curly brackets which doesn't stem from my code, please revise the text carefully.